# Slicing a string in Dart

Tags: dart

how do I slice a string in dart

Example: `"+5124343545"` I want to remove the first index(ie. the "+" sign). so output will look like `"5124343545"`

Comment: [`String.substring`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/substring.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void  main() {
  String string = '+5124343545';
  string = string.substring(1);
  print(string);
}
```

Output: 5124343545
Or maybe you want to do the following:

```
void main() {
  String string = '+5124343545';
  string = string.replaceFirst('+','');
  print(string);
}
```

In the second variant you have no risk to delete number instead plus symbol (if the input variable didn`t have a plus in the first position).

Answer (score 0):

Splice method is not available in dart.
The best and easy alternative is str.substring(0, 1)